# Are there recent depictions of Al Qaeda and/or ISIS as villains in Marvel Comics (non-movies)?

Tags: marvel, comics

After the tragedy of 9/11, Marvel had a few very iconic panels such as

[image: Captain America crying over the Twin Towers]

And

[image: Spidey looking at Ground Zero]

Are there recent Marvel depictions (depiction prior to December 1st, 2018), that actually drew and not just mentioned in dialog, of Al Qaeda or ISIS as a villain in one of their comics?  Books only, not interested in the movies.

Comment: Do you have examples of this ever happening? That would be a good place to start figuring out the last time.

Comment: @JoeW  Not really.  Batman and Robin had a few where the Joker teamed with Islamic terrorists.

Comment: I feel like "last time" is a very moveable thing too.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots You could use recent then.  I will edit.

Comment: @KDog: Better would be to bound your query such as "most recent depiction prior to December 1st, 2018" or the like. If you can constrain it to a narrow enough set of dates, you might be able to ask for all occurrences (broad or open-ended list questions are discouraged, but more constrained ones are fine, as are "has this ever happened?" questions that don't ask for every incidence).

Comment: I would question if it has ever happened espically since other content (movies) have removed references from middle east terrorists after 9/11 and changed them to be from other areas. Some of the John Clancy movies are examples of this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Al-Qaeda

In *Secret Avengers* #1 (2013), S.H.I.E.L.D. works to bring down Andras Bertesy, a Hungarian arms dealer also versed into dark arts. The guy is reported to want [to sell teleportation energy to Al-Qaeda cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UViD5.jpg), which would enable them to teleport into any building (say, the White House).

A deal takes place, with a "high-value American target" at stake. Skip some panels, a terrorist teleports into the Oval Office, only to be greeted by Nick Fury shooting at him. Now as the guy isn't formally introduced, I cannot 100% guarantee he is indeed Al-Qaeda, but given the above dialogue and his rather stereotypical look, he probably is.

[image: Terrorist is killed]

## ISIS

It's a tad bit "cheating" as the comic is a movie tie-in, but in *Avengers: Infinity War Prelude* #1 (2018), Sam, Steve and Natasha retrieve Chitauri-fueled weapons from terrorists; a truck bearing ISIS' flag (or something really close) is briefly shown.

[image: Natasha spots the terrorist shipment]

---

There is a *possible* Al-Qaeda character in *Marvel Comics Presents* #7 (2019). Wolverine travels the world in the search of a demon, who appears every decade in the "worst place on the world" (bomb sites, tsunamis, etc). In 2001, [he's depicted at Ground Zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y79WZ.jpg), and later in a fight with the following guy. While his faction is not mentioned, given the reference to 9/11, what a U.S. writer would think was one of the bane of the early 2000s, and Marvel's lack of subtility in general, I think it's possible he is meant to be a Taliban or Al-Qaeda (the two started as independent groups but later went on having  lot of connections).

[image: Wolverine in several fights and natural disasters]

Comment: nice work, pretty much what I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

According to the Marvel wiki, within the 616 universe, members of Al Qaeda have appeared in [Amazing Spider-Man Volume 2, #36](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_2_36) and [Secret Avengers Volume 2, #1](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Secret_Avengers_Vol_2_1). They appeared in the 1610 universe in [Ultimate Comics: the Ultimates Vol 1, #22](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Comics_Ultimates_Vol_1_22).

[image: Secret Avengers Vol 2 1 depiction of Al Qaeda]

[image: Ultimate Comics Ultimates Vol 1 22 depiction]

[image: Ultimate Comics Ultimates Vol 1 22 depiction]

Comment: For what it's worth the ASM issue is the one in the question, with Spidey looking at Ground Zero.

Comment: I upvoted, but it would be better to clarify these to the content context in the question.  Are they really villains or just, more or less, background noise, or just mentions?

Comment: @KDog in the _Ultimates_ case, they were a squad sent somewhere in the Afghanistan area to catch Osama Bin Laden. He wasn't here, though, and things went haywire when Wonder Man completely lost it. The soldiers themselves are referred to as being Taliban. Taliban and Al-Qaeda were different groups at first, but they went on to have enough connections for us to assume that the writers indeed meant Al-Qaeda (perhaps without naming it).